# cat command overwritten

Tags: yum, cat, system-recovery

By error I have execute "sudo nano cat filepathxxxx" and somehow I change the content.
The cat command is no longer working and I can't install it I tried to execute "yum install coreutils" and I get already installed, nothing to do Can you please tell me what I can add to get it back.
Regards,

Comment: I find a solution, to get cat command working again execute Yum reinstall coreutils

Comment: In order for that to happen you'd have to run nano in /bin and as root, is it really what you did?

Comment: step one: never call your text editor with `sudo`. also, was this executed in `/bin`? because if not, the "cat" file you edited would not be the `cat` executable. in any case, `yum install` is not `yum reinstall`

Answer (score 3):

Run `sudo yum reinstall coreutils` to refresh all the files in the `coreutils` package, including `/bin/cat`.

In the meantime, some things may stop working due to the broken `cat`. Here's a replacement which doesn't handle options, but should be enough for critical system scripts. Run `sudo nano /bin/cat` and enter that, then `sudo chmod 755 /bin/cat`.

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
  tee
else
  for x; do tee <"$x"; done
fi
```